# Search filter will do filter only on the current page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a search filter with pagination, it'll filter the content only on the current page and not on all the pages that I have.

Brief :
Assume that I'm on the first page and I have content 1 to 14. Now I'm going to search content 12 which is located on the second page....When I search, it'll not filter the content from the second page.

My JS for filter and pagination

```css
body{
    background-color: #333642;
    margin: 0;
}

/* CONTENT STYLING */

.red .content{
    background-color: tomato;
    padding: 10px;
    color: white;
    border:none;
    border-radius: 8px 8px 0px 0px;
    text-align: center;
}

.blue .content{
    background-color: dodgerblue;
    padding: 10px;
    color: white;
    border:none;
    border-radius: 8px 8px 0px 0px;
    text-align: center;
}

.green .content{
    background-color: green;
    padding: 10px;
    color: white;
    border:none;
    border-radius: 8px 8px 0px 0px;
    text-align: center;
}

.comedy .content{
    background-color: #131417;
    padding: 10px;
    color: white;
    border:none;
    border-radius: 8px 8px 0px 0px;
    text-align: center;
}


.content-title{
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 0 0 8px 8px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 8px;
}

/* SEARCH & fILTER */


/* PAGINATION */

.pagination a{
    margin: 5px 10px;
    border-radius: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
}

.pagination ul li{
    text-align: center;
}

.page-link {
  color: white;
  background-color: #333642;
  border: 2px solid #346767;
}

.page-item.disabled .page-link {
  color: white;
  background-color: #333642;
  border-color: #346767;
}

.page-item.active .page-link {
  z-index: 1;
  color: #fff; 
  background-color: #131417;
  border-color: #346767;

}

.page-link:focus, .page-link:hover {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #fff; 
}

.count{
  color: white;
}



/*

#333642
#131417

*/
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>My Website</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body style="background-color:#333642;">
  <!-- FILTER-SCRIPT -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/isotope-layout@3/dist/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>
  <!-- PAGINATION-SCRIPT -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twbs-pagination/1.4.2/jquery.twbsPagination.js"></script>

    <div class="container section">
      <div class="row mt-4">
        <div class="col-9">
          <input type="text" id="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search"></input>          
        </div>
        <div class="col-3">
          <button type="submit" id="btn" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Search</button>        
        </div>
    </div>
          <div id="filters" class="row mt-4">
        <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3 col-xl-3">
            <select id="filter-select1" class="form-control">
              <option value="">All</option>
              <option value="red">Red</option>
              <option value="green">Green</option>
              <option value="blue">Blue</option>
              <option value="comedy">Comedy</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3 col-xl-3">
          <select id="filter-select2" class="form-control">
            <option value="">All</option>
            <option value="der">Red</option>
            <option value="green">Green</option>
            <option value="blue">Blue</option>
            <option value="comedy">Comedy</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3 col-xl-3">
          <select id="filter-select3" class="form-control">
            <option value="">All</option>
            <option value="red">Red</option>
            <option value="green">Green</option>
            <option value="blue">Blue</option>
            <option value="comedy">Comedy</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3 col-xl-3">
          <select id="filter-select4" class="form-control">
            <option value="">All</option>
            <option value="red">Red</option>
            <option value="green">Green</option>
            <option value="blue">Blue</option>
            <option value="comedy">Comedy</option>
          </select>
        </div>

          </div>
    </div>

  <nav class="paginator text-center mt-4">
      <ul class="pagination flex-wrap justify-content-center"></ul>
  </nav>

  <div class="container">
    <div id="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="item red der col-6 col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6">
        <div class="content mt-4">
          <h1>content</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="content-title">
          <h3>fy Title 1</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="blue item col-6 col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6">
        <div class="content mt-4">
          <h1>content</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="content-title">
          <h3>My Title Qz 2</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="green item col-6 col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6">
        <div class="content mt-4">
          <h1>content</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="content-title">
          <h3>My Title 3</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="red item col-6 col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6">
        <div class="content mt-4">
          <h1>content</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="content-title">
          <h3>My Title 4</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="comedy item col-6 col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6">
        <div class="content mt-4">
          <h1>content</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="content-title">
          <h3>My Title 5</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="comedy item col-6 col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6">
        <div class="content mt-4">
          <h1>content</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="content-title">
          <h3>My Title 6</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="green item col-6 col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6">
        <div class="content mt-4">
          <h1>content</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="content-title">
          <h3>My Title 7</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="blue item col-6 col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6">
        <div class="content mt-4">
          <h1>content</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="content-title">
          <h3>My Title 8</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="green item col-6 col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6">
        <div class="content mt-4">
          <h1>content</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="content-title">
          <h3>My Title 9</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="red item col-6 col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6">
        <div class="content mt-4">
          <h1>content</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="content-title">
          <h3>My Title 10</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="comedy item col-6 col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6">
        <div class="content mt-4">
          <h1>content</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="content-title">
          <h3>My Title 11</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="blue item col-6 col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6">
        <div class="content mt-4">
          <h1>content</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="content-title">
          <h3>My Title 12</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="blue item col-6 col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6">
        <div class="content mt-4">
          <h1>content</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="content-title">
          <h3>My Title 13</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="red item col-6 col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6">
        <div class="content mt-4">
          <h1>content</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="content-title">
          <h3>My Title 14</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <h3 class="count text-center mt-4"></h3>

  <nav class="paginator text-center">
      <ul class="pagination flex-wrap justify-content-center"></ul>
  </nav>

  <script src="js/filter/filter.js"></script>
  <script src="js/pagination/page.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

//Filter Script

```
$(function() {

  var $grid = $('#container');
  $grid.isotope({
    itemSelector: '.item'
  });

  var filters = []; // A convenient bucket for all the filter options, 

  // Search event handlers
  // BUTTON-SEARCH 
  $('#btn').on('click', function() {
    filters[0] = $('#search')[0].value;
    runFilter();
  });

  $('#filter-select').on('change', function() {
    filters[1] = this.value;
    runFilter();
  });
  // and so on if more filters needed

  // The filter itself
  var runFilter = function() {
    $grid.isotope({
      filter: function() {
        if (filters[0]) {
          // at least some search text was entered:
          var qsRegex = new RegExp(filters[0], 'gi');

          // if the title doesn't match, eliminate it:
          if (!$(this).find('.content-title').text().match(qsRegex)) {
            return false;
          }
        }

        if (filters[1]) {
          // a category was selected; filter out others:
          if (!($(this).hasClass(filters[1]))) {
            return false;
          }
        }

        // etcetera, for any other filters 

        // successfully passed all conditions, so:
        return true;
      }
    });
  }
});
```

```js
//Pagination Script

var detect = function(width) {
if (width < 992) {
    callPagination(8);
}else if (width >= 992) {
    callPagination(12);
}};


var callPagination = function(pageSize) {
pageSize = pageSize;
pagesCount = $('.item').length;
var totalPages = Math.ceil(pagesCount / pageSize);

$('.pagination').twbsPagination({
    totalPages: totalPages,
    visiblePages: 3,
    onPageClick: function(event, page) {
        var startIndex = pageSize * (page - 1);
        var endIndex = startIndex + pageSize;
        $('.item')
            .hide()
            .filter(function() {
                var idx = $(this).index();
                return idx >= startIndex && idx < endIndex;
            })
            .show();
        $('.count').text('Page ' + page);
    }
});};

$(document).ready(function() {
var width = window.innerWidth;
detect(width)

$(window).resize(function() {
    var width = window.innerWidth;
    detect(width)
});});
```

Comment: Why not use the snippets to provide [mcve]

Comment: You seem to be using multiple 3rd party plugins - without details there's not much we can do to help.  They also probably conflict with each other.

Comment: https://codepen.io/JOHNakl/pen/BaNqxML here's a codepen link